# Creating and running tests from different folders

Tags: php, automated-tests, selenium-webdriver, codeception

I have a little problem with creating and running tests from different folders. Burn a lot of hours but have not found a solution yet. Using Codeception and Selenium2.

I have a structure:

```
C:\wamp\www\test\
```

Where i have codecept and codeception main files.

```
C:\wamp\www\test\tests
```

Where i have 3 types of test folders(acceptance, unit, functional), and 3 types of suite.yml with the same names.

And i have on disk D folder when i want put all my projects, this file is empty and there is no codeception files:

```
D:\try\projects
```

How i see this:

```
C:\wamp\www\test\ php codecept.phar run `D:\try\projects\Avia\login`
```

And codeception run only this test with 1 or more tests inside.
How create and run tests in this way? Maybe i'm wrong and there is another way to do that. So if it is, write please as example.

I missed a part with creating file in that directory because i don't know how exactly it works.But i can create full directory with all codeception files by typing command:

```
php codecept.phar bootstrap D:\try\projects
```

But it's not what i need.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that you want to run your tests against three different projects?